# How to make VSCODE show gcc output when compiling

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, gcc-warning

I'm trying to edit my tasks.json and/or launch.json to output warnings gcc would usually show when compiling C code with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags using *Run Without Debugging*.

When using the the *Run Without Debugging* option in VSCODE it seems to compile the program using the flags set in my workspace tasks.json file but it doesn't show me the output of gcc.
There's a *Task - build active file*-tab in the terminal section but it just shows:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc build active file <

Starting build...

Build finished successfully.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ten = 10;
    int two = 2;

    printf("Doing it right:\t");
    printf("%d minus %d is %d\n\n", ten, 2, ten - two);

    printf("Doing it wrong:\t");
    printf("%d minus %d is %d\n",ten); // Two arguments missing

    return 0;
}
```

Example of the desired output upon compiling:

```
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:13:23: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
   13 |     printf("%d minus %d is %d\n",ten); // Two arguments missing
      |                      ~^
      |                       |
      |                       int
example.c:13:29: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
   13 |     printf("%d minus %d is %d\n",ten); // Two arguments missing
      |                            ~^
      |                             |
      |                             int
```